# Launching activity on tapping in EditText box

Tags: android, android-edittext

By default in android whenever the user tap on any editText box , keyboard pops up .

I want that whenever the user tap on any editText box,it launches my activity along with the keyboard(keyboard thing is already handled by the framework) .

Answer (score 4):

For this you have to `override` `EditText` `onFocusChangeListener` like this

```
EditText edittxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.youredittext);
    edittxt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
        {
            if (hasFocus == true)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
         //start your activity here 
    }

});
```